# Two separate instances of one requirejs module, gl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working on a WebGL game for the browser. When doing WebGL programming, it's super useful to be able to use gl as a global (since you have to call functions on it a TON). However, I'd like to run this game in multiple canvases at once which means I need multiple gl contexts: one context per canvas.

It's good enough for me if I just pull gl in as a dependency at the top since I'm using requirejs:

```
define(['gl'], function(gl) {
  return function() {
    gl.drawArrays(...);
  };
});
```

However, I need this to return the ith context for the ith game. They can't share the context, each canvas must have its own. **So each canvas has to have a *separate* requirejs module, gl. Is this possible?**

For reference, gl.js looks like:

```
define(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
  gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  return gl;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are thinking wrong.

RequiereJs cannot resolve your problem. The only goal of it is to prevent scripts from running if required scripts did not run before.

To resolve your pb, you have to get familiar with the Object-Oriented Programing in Javascript.

You need to define an object class GL, and then instanciate x times :

in **gl.js** :

```
var GL = (function(){      
    // the constructor
    function GLClass(container, some, other, arguments){
        this.$container = document.getElementById(container);
        this.some = some; //...
        // ... other init instructions ...
    };

    // the different methods of this object ...
    GLClass.prototype.myFunc = function(str){
        // inside a method, this refers to the instance of the object.
        this.some = str;
    };
    GLClass.prototype.display = function(){
        this.$container.innerHTML = this.some;
    };

    // finally return the Constructor
    return GLClass;

})(); // don't forget the last parenthesis to execute immediately the previous code (aka declare and return the constructor in the GL var)

return GL; // needed to get the class name for requirejs.
```

In **another file** :

```
define(['gl'], function(GL) {
  // Then you can instance two separate objects :

  var myGl1 = new GL('gl1','some','other','arguments');
  var myGl2 = new GL('gl2','some','other','arguments');

  myGl1.myFunc('test1');
  myGl2.myFunc('test2');

  myGl1.display();
  myGl2.display();

});
```

I did a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/bDPde/) to show you a really simple example.

As you can see :

1. I keep only one load of gl.js.
2. I created two separate objects with their own properties.

Here is a really good post to get familiar with this : [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)